# Radius of convergence, power series

Tags: complex-analysis

So I'm stuck with the question: Find the radius of convergence for the power series:

$$f(z) = \sum^{ \infty}_{j=0} 2^{j} z^{j^2}$$

My issue is that there are two solutions depending if the $a_{n}$ is a perfect square or not, how should I approach this problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Precisely for cases like this one is that Cauchy-Hadamard is used. Observe the coefficients sequence is

$$a_n=\begin{cases}2^n,&n\;\text{ is a perfect square}\\{}\\0,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

and then

$$\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}=2\implies R=\frac12\;\text{is the convergence radius, by Cauchy Hadamard Formula}$$

Comment: How do you conclude the first thing, that $a_n$ is either 2^{n} or 0, that's the part I dont get

Comment: Look at the powers of $\;z\;$ . They are $\;0,\,1,\,4,\,9,\,16,\,...$ etc. So for this series to be considered a **power series** (i.e., with **consecutive** powers of $\;z\;$ ), we must write it , and consider it, as $$1+2z+0\cdot z^2+0\cdot z^3+4z^4+0\cdot z+\ldots+0\cdot z^8+8z^9+\ldots$$

Comment: I'm very grateful that you are willing to help me, but for what n would $a_n$ become 0?

Comment: ahh, I think I get it, thanks for the help!

Comment: @Stratbomber Any time. Tricks like this one are something that not very often is taught in school. One must struggle with this.